# Show an asymptotic property of a realization of an AR(1)

Tags: time-series, probability, self-study, stochastic-processes, autoregressive

Let

$$X_t = 0.9 \, X_{t-1} + \eta_t, \quad \eta_t \,\, \hbox{i.i.d.} \sim N(0,1)$$

Indeed, I want to show that a fixed realization $(\bar{X}_t)$ satisfies
\begin{equation}\tag{I}
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{1\leq t \leq n} |\bar{X}_{t}|=0
\end{equation}

Although it is a fixed realization, I don't know if it is feasible since we are dealing with stochastic elements. Thus another approach would be to try to show almost surely. So I have two questions.

First, how to show

\begin{equation}\tag{II}
\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left[ \max_{1\leq t \leq n} |X_{t} | \geq n^r \right]=0, \quad r < 1.
\end{equation}

Second question: this implies (I)?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this question, because as $n$ increases the maximum can never decrease, whence it's impossible for the limit to be $0$ unless every one of the $\bar X_t$ is zero.  I must be misinterpreting some of the symbols in $(I),$ but which ones?

Comment: Yes you are right. But maybe in probability I can have something similar. That's why I proposed (II).

Answer (score 2):

The asserted limit looks false to me.  With probability one you have $X_1 \neq 0$, which then implies:

$$0 < |X_1| \leqslant \max_{1 \leqslant t \leqslant n} |\bar{X}_t| \leqslant \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \max_{1 \leqslant t \leqslant n} |\bar{X}_t|.$$

Comment: How about if I enforce that $X_1 = 0$ with probability one?

Comment: I thought of something like this: denote $\kappa_n =  \max_{1\leq t \leq n} |X_{t} |$. By triangular inequality I have $\kappa_n \leq 0.9 \kappa_n + \max_{1\leq t \leq n} |\eta_{t} |$. Thus
$$\kappa_n \leq \frac{ \max_{1\leq t \leq n} |\eta_{t} | }{ 0.1 }$$But then I wouldn't know how to complete equation II for this case. Maybe analyze the second moments.

Comment: Even if the process starts at zero, it keeps oscillating, as new innovations $\eta_t$ come in. So still, why do you even expect the statement to be true? Is $\bar{X}_t$ maybe an average?

Comment: If you enforce $X_1=0$ then you just get the exact same problem via $X_2 \neq 0$ (which occurs with probability one).